# Why I have error in Odoo while using product.template

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

I'm trying to run a test task from the site https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/howtos/website.html

models.py

```
from odoo import models, fields, api

 class Teachers(models.Model):
    _name = 'academy.teachers'

    name = fields.Char()
    biography = fields.Html()
    course_ids = fields.One2many('academy.courses', 'teacher_id', string="Courses")

 class Courses(models.Model):
    
    _name = 'academy.courses'
    _inherit = 'product.template'
    teacher_id = fields.Many2one('academy.teachers', string="Teacher")
```

but when start odoo i have error

```
TypeError: Many2many fields academy.courses.taxes_id and product.template.taxes_id use the same table and columns - - -
```

don't understand how to remove this error
`Бany2many fields academy.courses.taxes_id and product.template.taxes_id use the same table and columns`

Comment: Your code example has nothing to do with the error. Please change it to the part where many2many fields are defined.

Comment: If I clean _inherit = 'product.template' then there is no error
I'm not defined many2many academy.courses.taxes_id

Comment: Oh totally missed that one. Why did you use that inherit there?

Comment: Because that's what it says in tutorial

Comment: Ah yes, i don't like that tutorial at all, but okay...

Answer (score 0):

When you inherit the `product.template` models and set the `_name` attribute, Odoo will copy the fields with all their attributes, and in case of `taxes_id`, `supplier_taxes_id` and `route_ids`, the `relation` is set manually which will be the same in `academy.courses` model.

When Odoo will try to [check whether other fields use the same schema](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/fields.py#L3697) it will fail and raise the error you see in the log.

***Edit:***

There are many references to `product.template` in model fields and methods. Even if you fix that error, the `product_tmpl_id` field still referece the product template model and this will prevent Odoo from creating any course.

When you change for example the product code it will check if the code is already used in product template model which is wrong.

Using only the `_inherit` attribute, you can`t inherit the product template model.

Comment: i did that but now i got another error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 644, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 302, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "academy_courses_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist

Comment: The `product.template` model is hard coded in product and attributes models, in fields and functions so you can't inherit the product template model using only the `_inherit` attribute